# Load Spring Security Attribute into a JSP variable

Tags: spring, security, jsp, variables

I would like to load a Spring Security attribute into a variable.

Variables:

- Boolean `edit` provided in the `POST` body (loading works fine)
- Boolean `isSupervisor` should be true if the user has the role supervisor (I don't know how to load it into an accessible variable. I've tried many different approaches and it didn't work.)

**Code:**

```
//set somehow the isSupervisor variable
//var isSupervisor = hasRole('ROLE_SUPERVISOR')    
<c:if test="${edit} and not isSupervisor">
... do something
</c:if>
```

Comment: Probably related issue: https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1611

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i found this solution:

```
<!-- Boolean isSupervisor -->
<!-- needed for creating the boolean: !isSupervisor -->
<c:set var="isSupervisor" value="false" />
<sec:authorize ifAllGranted="ROLE_SUPERVISOR">
    <c:set var="isSupervisor" value="true" />
</sec:authorize>


<c:if test="${!edit || (edit && !isSupervisor)}">
    // do some opertations...
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Spring Security JSP Taglib Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html)

It provides the following example:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('supervisor')">

  This content will only be visible to users who have
  the "supervisor" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.

</sec:authorize>
```